# Singular Cohomology satisfies the Mittag-Leffler Condition on CW complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, limits-colimits

Is this true?

> Let $H$ be singular cohomology. On an arbitrary CW complex $X$, given a filtration $X^0 \subseteq X^1 \subseteq \cdots X^n \subseteq \cdots \subseteq X$. Then 
>   $$H^*(X) \cong \varprojlim H^*(X^n)$$

I have looked this up, and it seems to me, this only holds for cohomology theories satisfying the Mittag Leffler condition.

But this has been an essential ingredient in the proof of Leray Hirsch Theorem. [On page 12, Part 6.) of this notes](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/bordism-skript.pdf).

What am I missing?

Comment: The Mittag-Leffler-condition is a property applicable to inverse systems . But what is a cohomology theory satisfying the Mittag Leffler condition? You cannot expect that for *any* direct system $\mathcal{X}$ of spaces you get an inverse system $H^*(\mathcal{X})$ of abelian groups which satisfies ML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true for arbitrary filtrations.  But the filtrations used in the proof of the Leray-Hirsch theorem are very special, such that for fixed $i$, the maps $H^i(X^{n+1})\to H^i(X^n)$ are isomorphisms for all sufficiently large $n$.  This in particular implies the Mittag-Leffler condition.

Alternatively (and I think this is the argument the notes you are reading has in mind), these filtrations have the property that for fixed $i$ the map $\pi_i(X_n)\to \pi_i(X)$ is an isomorphism for all sufficiently large $n$.  By Hurewicz this then implies the map $H^i(X)\to H^i(X^n)$ is an isomorphism for sufficiently large $n$ which immediately implies the map to the inverse limit is also an isomorphism.

Comment: Hi Eric, in retrospect, why is it that $\pi_i(X_n) \rightarrow \pi_i(X)$ is an isomoprhism for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: For the skeletal filtration on $X$, this is immediate from CW approximation.  For the pulled-back filtration on $E$, it follows from comparing the homotopy groups of $E$ and $E^{(n)}$ to those of $X$ and $X^{(n)}$ via the long exact sequences of the fibration.  (This is basically the argument at the start of step (4), except that $\pi_*(Y)\to\pi_*(X)$ is only an isomorphism in low degrees.)

Comment: Hi Eric, so I have one last conercen, how does one deduce $H^i((X) \rightarrow H^i(X^n)$ is an isomorphism? The version I know of requiries $n$- connectedness, or there is the relative version, pg366 of Hatchers. I have applied your trick to another statement, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204957/serre-fibration-and-mittag-leffler-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1 , is it right?